# Why is this python code running twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code

```
import random

print("Hello", end="")
print("twice")
```

and a screenshot of the code

[image]

When I execute this code it for some reason is running twice. The problem seems to be from the **import random** statement, because if I either remove that statement or import some other module it works fine.

What could be the reason for this, should I reinstall Python on my system.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with python.

The reason is simple:

Your module is importing itself (because it is also named `random`) - this has to do with the lookup mechanics of python. python will try to import from your root folder first, before modules from pythonpath are imported.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory
>     when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

Comment: Oh my god! This was happening to me and it took me ages to figure out! Thanks!

Comment: Hello. I'm a python beginner and my script didn't import itself but it did run twice (compiled to exe and started from the windows explorer, or called from another application). Eventually managed to figure this is due to the syntax error i made, i used "exit(code)" instead of "sys.exit(code)" so the runtime error was occurring, but still i'm a bit puzzled, can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 6):

Since your file (module) is called `random.py`, `import random` will import this very file.

Now, what does "import" mean?
The statement `import something` will cause Python to lookup the name `something`, starting with the current directory.
Therefore, `import random` will result in an import of this very file, since its name will shadow the build-in `random`.
Besides, if the name to import is already in the namespace, then the `import` statement is ignored.

Once the module to import has been located, its code is executed.

As a result, the flow of your script is as follow:

- Lookup the `random.py` name
- Add `random` to the namespace
- Execute the code contained in `random.py`

  - The `random` name already exists in the namespace, so the `import random` statement is ignored
  - Print the text
- Print the text

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is you've named the script `random.py` and inside it you import `random`.

`random` will *not* import the built-in `random` module but, rather, the `random` module you've created. This leads to the script executing the same statements twice (and also leads to other ugly errors if you tried and import something from `random`, like `from random import randrange`.)

Renaming the script leads to normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because your scripts is called random.py, so when you `import random` you are executing your script as well. Mind to name correctly your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

your python script is named `random.py` so when you import random it import itself , in  python when you import module it will run it.

therefor you get print twice.
rename your script or remove the import